# for loop to include image source

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I am using a for loop to display data from session storage. Currently it is being displayed like this:

- 21.62 /weather/icons/01d.png
- 18.16 /weather/icons/02d.png
- 19.05 /weather/icons/01d.png
- 18.6 /weather/icons/10d.png
- 11.43 /weather/icons/10d.png

(This is showing the main temp for that day, followed by link to weather icon.)

And below this list there is a single icon being displaying (I don't know why it is outputting just one). I would like all the icons to display, in the list like this one icon does i.e. `<img id="icon" src="/weather/icons/10d.png" alt="Weather icon">`

But for some reason the list doesn't seem to be fully taking into account: `$('#icon').attr('src', iconUrl);`

```
var forecastMainEl;
var forecastIconEl;
var iconUrl;
var iconEl;

function populateContent(forecast)
{
    forecastMainEl = sessionStorage.getItem("forecast");
    forecastIconEl= sessionStorage.getItem("forecastIcon");

    var objMain = JSON.parse(forecastMainEl);
    var objIcon = JSON.parse(forecastIconEl);

    var forecastLength;
    var forecastText;
    var g;


        forecastLength = objMain.length;
        forecastText = "<ul>";
        for (g = 0; g < forecastLength; g++) {

            iconUrl = "/weather/icons/" + objIcon[g] + ".png";
            $('#icon').attr('src', iconUrl);

            forecastText += "<li class='forecastMain'>" + objMain[g] + "</li>" + "<li class='forecastIcon'>" + iconUrl + "</li>";
        }
        forecastText += "</ul>";

        //outputs result
        document.getElementById("forecastList").innerHTML = forecastText;


}
function init(){
    populateContent(forecast);
}

init();
```

html:

```
<div id="forecastMain"></div>
<div id="forecastList"></div>
<div id="forecastIcon"></div>
<div><img id="icon" src="" alt="Weather icon"></div>
```

Comment: Based on your code, you only have one icon, and you're setting the source on it again and again in your loop. You need to dynamically create icons.

Comment: `var objIcon` is bringing back an array. 01d, 02d, 10d are icons. When I do `console.log(objIcon[g]);` inside the for-loop I am getting all of them back e.g. `10d`, `02d`, `01d` which are in the url pointing to the icon png with same name.

Comment: Inside the list it is displaying like: `<li class="forecastIcon">/weather/icons/10d.png</li>` and not taking into account `$('#icon').attr('src', iconUrl);`

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you're going for here. You have one icon, and you keep changing its source here: `$('#icon').attr('src', iconUrl);`...but you're expecting to see multiple icons? If you want to see **N** number of icons, create **N** number of icon tags and set their source. As it stands now, you're repeatedly setting the source of a single icon tag.

Comment: I was yes. Reason being is the for loop is able to display each `objIcon[g]` successfully as part of the `iconUrl` variable which I have in the forecastText i.e. `<li class='forecastIcon'>" + iconUrl + "</li>` . And so I thought that because it can output each iconUrl like `/weather/icons/01d.png` that I could make this an img source with the use of `$('#icon').attr('src', iconUrl);` inside the loop also.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this in another way which is:

```
forecastText += "<li class='forecastMain'>" + objMain[g] + "</li>" + "<li class='forecastIcon'>" + "<img id='icon'" + "src='/weather/icons/" + objIcon[g] + ".png'" + "alt='Weather icon'>" + "</li>";
```

This no longer requires this:

```
        iconUrl = "/weather/icons/" + objIcon[g] + ".png";
        $('#icon').attr('src', iconUrl);
```

But thought that may have been a cleaner way so if anyone has a better way of doing this I look forward to hearing. Thanks.